# Connecting multiple local network with same IP range with Azure VNet

Tags: networking, azure

We are building a SaaS application where multiple tenants will be using single deployed application. Some tenants wants to access this application over vpn only (for security reasons). To achieve this we need to set site to site connectivity with tenant's network. But we are facing following problem.

Two tenant may be using same IP range. How can we connect Azure Vnet with these different local network with same IP range. [I am not sure but I guess, connecting these local network with two different vnet first and then connecting these two vnet to main vnet will work, but this will complicate the system].

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve your problem easily. This is a basic issue with IP address range allocation and isn't restricted to Azure. You could have some form of on-premise solution rolled out that would meet your requirements by laying down a range you control that your customer then needs to connect their internal network to.  Even doing that you'd probably still have problems where your Azure VNET private IP address range overlaps a customer's internal range which is highly likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out with customer to make sure that all participating networks in the VPN have different address space.
This can be easily work out at on premise level, it should be easy to have different address space even if everybody is using say  192.168 series.
NATing at on premise networks should be straight forward.